# When to use f1_macro vs f1_weighted?

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic, classification, f1

My dataset is imbalanced. The labels are binary. I'm training 2 logistic regression models.
For the first one, I didnt balance the model with `class_weight` and used f1_macro. Was it correct for me to use f1_macro?

for the 2nd Logistic model I set `class_weight='balanced'`. Should I use f1_macro or f1_wighted here?
[image: Here is the img of the 2nd model]

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no single correct answer to this problem. Which metric and loss function to use depends on your problem, data, and business case. Each choice has advantages and disadvantages.

Using class weight in `LogisticRegression` affects your loss function, and makes the loss function put equal importance to the classes so that the minority class doesn't get lost in the calculations.

The `scoring` variable in grid search object affects how the test success is measured. The F1 score depends on which class is assumed to be positive, therefore calculating F1 score for both classes and averaging them is a good idea but doing this weighted or not usually depends on your problem. If you want to treat the classes equally, you can do weighted mean. But, if your problem cares more about the positive class, you may do a plain average.

Comment: My dataset is about employee attrition prediction. I just want to know which employees are likely to stay in the company and which ones are likely to leave. So it's a good idea to put equal importance on both. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea. But, at the same time, every problem has some imbalance, and we do not see class weights being used every time in ML. Yet, we get good performance. Experimenting is a natural part of the ML cycle.